# Send(Response) data(Obj) from node to Angular using POST

Tags: node.js, express

What I'm trying to accomplish?

->I have executed login query, if the login query is true, then send the role of particular user. So, I'm executing 2 queries, 1 for validation and other to send the role of user.I'm able to store the role in object, but not able to send that object to Angular.I tried using res.json(obj(['key'])), res.end(JSON.stringify(obj['Key'])); none of them are working.
Any other methods?

Code :

```
var Role_id = {
  Role: ''
};

router.post('/login', function(req, httpres, next) {
      console.log("Inside the login api");
      const username = req.body.username;
      const password = req.body.password;
      console.log(username, password)
      pool.query(" select exists(SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = $1 AND password = $2 ) ", [username, password])
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            console.log('success', data)
            if (data.rows[0].exists) {
              httpres.json({
                status: true,
                message: 'Login  Succesfully',
                parameters: req.body
              });
              var re = ("SELECT role_id from users where username ='" + username + "'  AND  password = '" + password + "'")
              console.log(" re ", re)
              pool.query("SELECT role_id from users where username ='" + username + "' AND  password = '" + password + "'")
                .subscribe(
                  data => {
                    console.log("data anonymous...", data.rows[0].role_id)
                    Role_id['Role'] = data.rows[0].role_id;
                    console.log("This data has to be read", Role_id['Role']);
                    //  httpres(JSON.stringify(Role_id['Role']));
                    // httpres.json(Role_id['Role']);
                    httpres.send(Role_id['Role']);
                    //    httpres.json({
                    //     parameters:req.Role_id['Role']
                    //   });
                  }, err => {
                    httpres.send('error');
                  }
                }
              else {
                httpres.send('error');
              }

            }, err => {
              console.log('error', err)
              httpres.send('error');
            })
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your are trying to send the response twice, and that's not possible. You can only send one response. Probably your are receiving the response from this code:
httpres.

```
json({
   status: true,
   message: 'Login  Succesfully',
   parameters: req.body
});
```

but not from the next codes. So, if you need to send all the information in the response, you should add it to one object and send the whole object at the end. Other case is not going to work.

Let me know if it helps.